# how to redirect result of linux time command to some file

Tags: linux

I'm running the following command (on Ubuntu)

```
time wget 'http://localhost:8080/upLoading.jsp' --timeout=0
```

and get a result in the command line

```
real    0m0.042s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I've tried the following:

```
time -a o.txt wget 'http://localhost:8080/upLoading.jsp' --timeout=0
```

and get the following error

```
-a: command not found
```

I want to get the result to be redirected to some file. How can I do that?

Comment: Probably you are using bash, and it has `time` built-in command. (see `help time`) Your command should use  `/usr/bin/time` to work properly (to discover where the binary of time is use `which time`). Considering this, you must use: `time -o out.txt -a ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can direct the `stdout` output of any commmand to a file using the `>` character.
To *append* the output to a file use `>>`

Note that unless done explicitly, output to `stderr` will still go to the console. To direct *both* `stderr` and `stdout` to the same output stream use

```
   command 2>&1 outfile.txt (with bash)
```

or

```
   command >& outfile.txt (with t/csh)
```

If you are working with `bash` [All about redirection](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) will give you more details and control about redirection.

Comment: Consider `/usr/bin/time` as I commented above. And so, use something like `/usr/bin/time -o outfile.txt -a ...`

Answer (score 12):

-a is only understood by the time binary (/usr/bin/time), When just using time you're using the bash built-in version which does not process the -a option, and hence tries to run it as a command.

```
/usr/bin/time -o foo.txt -a wget 'http://localhost:8080/upLoading.jsp' --timeout=0
```

Comment: the both -a and -o did not worked. The solution was 2 > foo.txt

Comment: I believe this is actually the correct answer. When calling time, call /usr/bin/time instead of using the shell's builtin which does not support the advanced options.

Comment: ... as long as you are using linux, I guess. OS X's `usr/bin/time` doesn't support `-o`.

Answer (score 7):

Checking `man time`, I guess what you need is

```
time -o o.txt -a ...
```

(Note you need *both* -a and -o).

[EDIT:] If you are in bash, you must also take care to write

```
/usr/bin/time
```

(check manpage for explanation)

Comment: Check Adam's comment (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11082413/384689), this is probably the solution

Comment: Hhmm, I cannot see it neither ... so I edited my answer. Hope this helps

Comment: I added a comment to this consideration in the question and also commented in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
\time 2> time.out.text command

\time -o time.out.text command
```

This answer based on earlier comments. It is tested it works. The advantage of the `\` over `/usr/bin/` is that you don't have to know the install directory of `time`.

These answers also only capture the time, not other output.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the `time` from GNU writes it's output to *stderr* and if you want to redirect it to file, you can use --output=PATH parameter of `time`

See this http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time

And if you want to redirect *stdout* to some file, you can use `> filename` to create file and fill it or `>> filename` to append to some file after the initial command.

If you want to redirect *stderr* by yourself, you can use `$ command >&2 your_stderr_output`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/usr/bin/time` since many shells have their own implementation of `time` which may or may not support the same flags as `/usr/bin/time`

so change your command to

```
  /usr/bin/time -a -o foo.txt wget ....
```

Comment: I added this comment in the question to evince it.

Answer (score 0):

How about your LANG ?

```
$ time -ao o.txt echo 1
bash: -ao: コマンドが見つかりません

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ export|grep LANG
declare -x LANG="ja_JP.utf8"

$ LANG=C time -ao o.txt echo 1
1

$ cat o.txt
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1984maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+158minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
command 2> log.txt
```

and the real-time output from "command" can be seen in another console window with:

```
tail -f log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
( time command ) |& tee output.txt
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115980/how-can-i-redirect-time-output-and-command-output-to-the-same-pipe

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with `>` if you want to redirect the output.

For example:

```
time wget 'http://localhost:8080/upLoading.jsp' --timeout=0 > output.txt 2>&1
```

`2>&1` says to redirect STDERR to the same file.

This command will erase any output.txt files and creates a new one with your output. If you use `>>` it will append the output at the end of any existing output.txt file. If it doesn't exist, it will create it.